# How to filter Remote Desktop connection in Event Log filter

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log

I need to see only success/fail logs for Remote Desktop connection. I want to monitor who (what username), when (datetime) and where (ip address) tried to connect to my remote server.

How do I filter this in Event Log in MS Windows Server 2008 R2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if logging is enabled. You can use Basic windows logging using the policy setting "Audit Logon Events". You can then filter for these events as described here: [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd630944.aspx)

If you need some more features (in the future) I recommend installing [Secure RDP](http://www.2x.com/securerdp/).